# Integral involving double exponentials

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, approximation-theory

I am trying to estimate the growth in time of a certain quantity. In order to do this, I have to evaluate the following integral:

$\int_0^{+\infty} \exp(-b x)\exp(-c\,t \exp(-a x \log x)) dx$

with $a,b$ and $c$ positive. I only need to know what happens at large $t$. Any ideas?

I have tried to use a saddle point approximation, but failed miserably. Perhaps I am doing something silly...

Comment: As a very first approximation, the function $e^{-a x\log x}$ has a major lobe between $0$ and $1$ with a single maximum $(1/e,e^{a/e})$ so the integral should roughly decrease like $e^{-ce^{a/e}}t$.

Comment: Dear Yves, thank you for your comment. Your expression seems to grow with t. Is this a typo?

Comment: Absolutey, $t$ should be in the exponential $e^{-ce^{a/e}t}$. Sorry. The fraction is $a/e$.

Comment: Sorry again, on second thoughts my reasoning is quite wrong. Because of the negative exponent, the maximum gives a smaller contribution to the integral and doesn't dictate the global behavior

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you are correct. Your result is what one would get by a naive implementation of the steepest descent method (which I did not manage to make it work) because of what you just pointed out.

Comment: For large $t$, it seems that the function starts with very small values, has a smooth single maximum (requiring the Lambert function I guess :( ), and quickly joins the exponential $e^{-bx}$.